# Remote Enroll face using Zkteco not working

Tags: zkteco

We try to Remote enroll User face using Zkteco SDT, while issuing command from SDK to Device Face enroll screen is appears on Device and Face also capturing the device. But after completing this No Face template is Stored on device. Device model is ESSL AI Mars. https://www.esslsecurity.com/face/aiface-mars.

Please anybody know the solution, please help

Thanks in advance.
Jagadeesh V.R.

Same thing working perfectly on device Uface 302  https://www.esslsecurity.com/face/uface302